# Passing complex objects to file in android

Tags: android, json, class, button, serialization

The idea is that I want to pass the instance of Buttons/EditTexts/TextViews/Classes/etc. and save it to a file in android then extract it to re-launch the activity next time it's visited.

**Is it even possible to do it?**

**I have tried**

- Serializable, but realized it can't be done without declaring those objects as **transient** which aren't affected by the serialization
- Parcelable, also same problem
- JSONObject, couldn't re-cast the object fetched into a Button/Layout/etc..
- GSon, got an infinite recursive loop

Please, any help available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never serialize UI elements such as `Buttons` or `Layouts`.
Rather save the data behind the UI, such as the texts, maybe some flags etc.

I'd recommend using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for that.

Comment: So there's no possible way like saving the state of an UI element and then re-create the element from it's past state? @FD_

Comment: Just think of the Model-View-Controller pattern: The views should just represent the data, which has to be saved separately. In this spirit, while there might be a way to do it, DON'T try it.

Comment: Also, have a look at how many fields `Views` have and how few of them you need - imagine the waste of space if you just serialize the UI.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced now, thanks for taking the time to clear that out.
I just don't understand why the hate on this website, I'm only here to learn and I've already searched a lot for an answer and couldn't get it else where

Comment: Sorry if anything I wrote sounded like offense - it certainly was not meant as such. As for the downvote you got, I am afraid the downvoter did not even leave a comment on the reason.

Comment: No that wasn't meant for you, on the contrary! Thanks a lot I really appreciate it and I accepted your answer because it finally helped me understand the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SharedPreferences` thats why it exist. You can create a private `SharedPreferences` for you application and declare a unique key for each attribute you have to save. Each attribute/value of your `SharedPreferences` should also have a `Default` value (A value you get when you are trying to retrieve a value that was not set before)

This **[Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)** will help you understand it

Comment: No, you can`t save the whole Object for sure. You can store its state (e.g. `textView.getText()` **Text** for the texts, `toggleButton.getState()` **Boolean** or `toggleBotton.isPressed()` **Boolean**...etc

Comment: Thumbs up for your answer thanks a lot for taking the time to help me